# Highcharts - Gauge chart data label not positioning correctly

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I'm building a vertical gauge and am having problems applying a custom image in place of the default marker.

Although the image renders, it's placement is off. I can't seem to get it to point exactly where the marker is positioned and I'm not sure if applying a static offset value to the 'y' attribute is the right approach.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ptezqnbf/).

```js
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column',
                marginBottom: 25,
                marginTop: 70,
                marginLeft: 65,
                marginRight: 10,
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['One'],
                lineColor: 'white',
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                tickLength: 0,
                min: 0,
                max: 2
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    animation: false,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 9026,
                tickInterval: 9026,
                tickLength: 0,
                tickWidth: 0,
                tickColor: '#C0C0C0',
                gridLineColor: '#C0C0C0',
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                minorTickInterval: 25,
                minorTickWidth: 0,
                minorTickLength: 0,
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                title: null,
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        if (this.isFirst || this.isLast) {
                            return this.value;
                        }
                    },
                    x: 0
                },
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [
            {
                data: [4513],
                color: {
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, 'red'],
                        [1, 'orange']
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                data: [4513],
                color: {
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, 'orange'],
                        [1, 'green']
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                type: 'scatter',
                data: [3120],
                marker: {
                    enabled: true,
                    symbol: 'circle'
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter: function () {

                        return '<img width="40px" height="40px"  src="http://icongal.com/gallery/image/57585/small_arrow_black_monotone_left.png" />'
                    },
                    enabled: true,
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3,
                    y: 2,
                    overflow: "justify"
                }
            }
            ]

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width: 178px; height: 242px;"></div>
```

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: i think you will have to take an account of the image height to place the marker exactly on the dot. The image you are rendering is 40*40 with some spacing on top and bottom, so your marker tip should be adjusted with some static y value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should adjust the image position via x, y properties.

```
      x: 0,
      y: 30,
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/ptezqnbf/1/

or even better, use [renderer.image](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.image) and control the position directly.

```
    function renderImage() {
      var chart = this,
        point = chart.get('point'),
        imgWidth = 40,
        imgHeight = 40;

      if (!chart.dataLabelImg) {
        chart.dataLabelImg = this.renderer.image('http://icongal.com/gallery/image/57585/small_arrow_black_monotone_left.png', -1000, -1000, imgWidth, imgHeight).add(point.series.dataLabelsGroup);
      }

      chart.dataLabelImg.attr({
        x: point.graphic.x + (imgWidth - 15) / 2,
        y: point.graphic.y - (imgHeight - 10) / 2
      });
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/tpp1gdau/1/